# How do I prevent Grails from auto-reloading certain files?

Tags: grails, emacs

When using Emacs to edit a Grails source file, Emacs will temporarily create [hidden write-lock files](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html) alongside the source file. For example, if editing `com/example/MyController`, one might see:

```
rob@machine:~/app$ ls -la grails-app/controllers/com/example/
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 3 rob rob 4096 2011-12-03 13:38 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 rob rob 3883 2012-01-03 13:57 MyController.groovy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 rob rob   26 2012-01-04 09:32 .#MyController.groovy -> rob@machine.2136:1324674574
```

When this file gets created during a `run-app`, Grails notices it and tries to compile it, often yielding compilation errors in the `run-app` console logs:

```
| Error 2012-01-04 09:32:51,207 [Thread-38] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin [controllers:2.0.0] could not reload changes to file [/home/rob/app/grails-app/controllers/com/example/.#MyController.groovy]: Dynamic method is<Artefact>Class(artefactClass) requires a single Class parameter
Message: Dynamic method is<Artefact>Class(artefactClass) requires a single Class parameter
   Line | Method
->> 629 | doCall in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure5
```

<sub>*It's possible that this only happens when using the spring-security-core plugin, but I haven't tested it without the plugin installed.*</sub>

I believe this only happens in Grails 2.0; I never observed it in 1.3.7 or earlier.

Is there any way to have Grails ignore these files when automatically recompiling during `run-app`? A general answer for controlling what files do and do not get reloaded would be ideal.

<sub>An authoritative answer of "no, this is not possible" is also acceptable to me. I understand that this may just not be possible via configuration, in which case I'll probably open a JIRA enhancement.</sub>

Comment: I'd like to know how to control what files it looks for and doesn't (not jut how to exclude them).  I know that in a plugin project there is a watchedResources list that is available to define which resources to watch for changes on, but I'm not sure how to configure this in a non-plugin grails project.

Comment: @JarredOlson - I agree - I've updated my question to ask for a more general answer if one exists.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that there's *probably not* a way to do this via configuration, and this question might end up as a Grails feature request. It's not super-urgent (to me, anyway); these errors don't really hose anything, they're just annoying to see running across the console.

Comment: I agree, but I'm a big fan of scaffolding and when you install templates and are editing the templates those changes don't get picked up and auto-reloaded so I waste a lot of time stopping and restarting the server.

Comment: @JarredOlson - Yeah, although I don't know if that's a trivial change. I doubt that (if it were possible to control the list of auto-reloaded files) it'd be possible to just add the templates and have Grails magically know that everything should be re-scaffolded. There'd probably have to be core changes to Grails for that. Might be a different enhancement request?

Comment: This is a workaround, but if you could have emacs write it's backup files with a different extension (like vim's ".un~" ending), you'd likely avoid the problem.  I'm betting that it's scanning for **/*.java and **/*.groovy and the files that are being written fit that pattern.

Comment: @TedNaleid - A good suggestion, although it doesn't look like I can do that with good ol' Emacs lisp and put it in my `.emacs`. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/651517/29995) I'd probably have to modify the source and rebuild it, which would be a lot of work, and also not as portable.

Comment: @Jarred, we ended up with a piece of code: `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.scaffolding.view.ScaffoldingViewResolver.scaffoldedViews.clear()` - can be done in runtime. We have an internal controller with an action doing this.

Comment: @VictorSergienko did you just setup a dumb controller with an action that you invoke to clear the scaffolded views?

Comment: @Jarred - Yes. Though, we also have a whole web UI for Groovy console in our applications, in which used to debug this kind of code.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the patch, but it looks like this was recently addressed by Graeme:

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/c201492dfa47419356fbfea2031d22755ea61fe9

Line 224 excludes files starting with a dot (ie. emacs write locks)

See also: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8539 which indicates that this could show up in 2.0.1

Comment: Had a look at the patch and it does look like that'll fix the reloads I'm seeing with emacs lock files as well. I may wait for it to make it into an official release to test it (and subsequently accept this answer). Thanks for the heads up!